# Expectation of a normal random variable with random mean

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mean, expected-value

Let $X(y) \sim N(y,2)$ where $y \sim F[1,10]$. How do I express the expected value of $X$? Is the expectation taken over the joint distribution of $X,y$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll use [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
$$E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]=E[Y]=\frac{10}{10-2}=5/4$$